# JavaScript Canvas White Screen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm really frustrated right now, JS never works for me. I don't know what little mistake I made this time, I'll be grateful if you point it out. I don't want an animation or anything, I'd be happy if someone tells me the error.

```
window.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth();
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight();

var ship = function() {
this.x = canvas.width/2;
this.y = canvas.height/2;
this.velocityX = 0;
this.velocityY = 0;
this.accelerationX = 0;
this.accelerationY = 0;

this.show = function() {
  //background
  context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
  context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  //update
  this.velocityX += this.accelerationX;
  this.velocityY += this.accelerationY;
  this.x += this.velocityX;
  this.y += this.velocityY;

  //draw
  context.save();
  context.translate(this.x,this.y) ;
  context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
  context.fillRect(0,0,20,30);
  context.restore();
};
};


var myship = new ship();
myship.show();
};
```

Comment: What color is the `canvas` on the screen?

Comment: I did that because I am neither able to view the black rect nor the black object, I get a white screen

Comment: No, I tried JSHint as well. I'm doing this on codepen.

Comment: To see errors, right click, then click Inspect. CodePen's console doesn't show errors `:(`. Here is error: `window.innerWidth is not a function`

Comment: Yes, I tried 'Analyze JS' which uses JS Hint to check for errors. The console also seems to be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues ...

**1.** `innerWidth / innerHeight` isn't a method / function, it's a property of the `window` object. so, the   correct form would be `window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight`

**2.**  You aren't able to view the `ship` object, as you set both the *background's* and *ship's* `fillStyle`   to **black**. so, either change `fillStyle` of the *background* or the *ship* to a different color.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var ship = function() {
    this.x = canvas.width / 2;
    this.y = canvas.height / 2;
    this.velocityX = 0;
    this.velocityY = 0;
    this.accelerationX = 0;
    this.accelerationY = 0;
    this.show = function() {
        //background
        context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
       
       //update
        this.velocityX += this.accelerationX;
        this.velocityY += this.accelerationY;
        this.x += this.velocityX;
        this.y += this.velocityY;
        
        //draw ship
        context.save();
        context.translate(this.x, this.y);
        context.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 30);
        context.restore();
    };
};
var myship = new ship();
myship.show();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```